# Problem with the html page on Android

Tags: android, html, emulation

I'm trying to open a html-page in WebView (and in Browser) in 2.2SDK-Emulator, but i get always this message:

***"This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 68: opening and ending tags mismatch: meta line 0 and head"***

Then i tried to open the same page on two devices and there is no problem with it. Now i open the same app in 1.6SDK-Emulator

Does anybody have any ideas, what happens? Can i somehow see the html-code of the page?!

**UPD:**

HTML code will be generated on server. That's why it's not so well readable. I replaced a bit all src values. They all are correct.

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/><title>title</title></head><body><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td><img src="..._0_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._1_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._2_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._3_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._4_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._5_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._6_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._7_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._8_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td><td><img src="..._9_0.png" alt="" border="0"/></td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

**UPD2:**

ok, the server guys added closing of tags (meta and img), now i don't get any parser errors anymore. See the code above

But i don't see any images now.

**UPD3:**

We've got it. It was the sever, who says that the page type is xml instead of it's html.

Comment: can you add your  html code plz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `meta` tag is not closed.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td><img src="..._0_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._1_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._2_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._3_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._4_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._5_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._6_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._7_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._8_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td><img src="..._9_0.png" alt="" border="0"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It was first also my idea, but why then i can see it on devices? One of them has Android 2.2. on it?

Comment: And i look also to structure of a html page on w3school. They have in their examples not closed meta tags too http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.3 Another strange thing, i loaded that html code with loadData and also had no problems with it

Comment: ok, the server guys added closing of tags (meta and img), now i don't get any parser errors anymore, but i don't see any images